# Python cPickle unable to load an OCR model library

Tags: python, ocr

I have just installed ocropus OCR with all dependencies in my windows 7 machine. (I am using 32bit python 2.7) It seems to be working fine except that I cannot load the default OCR model: en-default.pyrnn.gz. , and receiving a Traceback. I am using the following syntax:

```
python ocropus-rpred -m en-default.pyrnn.gz book\0001\*.png
```

here is the error

```
INFO: #inputs47
# loading object /usr/local/share/ocropus/en-default.pyrnn.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "ocropus-rpred" line 109, in <module>
        network = ocrolib.load_object(args.model,verbose=1)
    File "C:\anaconda32\lib\site-packages\ocrolib\common.py", line 513, in load_object
        return unpickler.load()
    EOFError
```

I have checked the file is not empty; also double checked the binary mode flag enabled i.e. "wb" and "rb"; also converted the newlines of common.py using dos2unix. I am being unable to unable to solve this problem. If anyone have expereinced similar issues, kindly share.

```
import cPickle
import gzip

def save_object(fname,obj,zip=0):
    if zip==0 and fname.endswith(".gz"):
        zip = 1
    if zip>0:
        # with gzip.GzipFile(fname,"wb") as stream:
        with os.popen("gzip -9 > '%s'"%fname,"wb") as stream:
            cPickle.dump(obj,stream,2)
    else:
        with open(fname,"wb") as stream:
            cPickle.dump(obj,stream,2)

def unpickle_find_global(mname,cname):
    if mname=="lstm.lstm":
        return getattr(lstm,cname)
    if not mname in sys.modules.keys():
        exec "import "+mname
    return getattr(sys.modules[mname],cname)

def load_object(fname,zip=0,nofind=0,verbose=0):
    """Loads an object from disk. By default, this handles zipped files
    and searches in the usual places for OCRopus. It also handles some
    class names that have changed."""
    if not nofind:
        fname = ocropus_find_file(fname)
    if verbose:
        print "# loading object",fname
    if zip==0 and fname.endswith(".gz"):
        zip = 1
    if zip>0:
        # with gzip.GzipFile(fname,"rb") as stream:
        with os.popen("gunzip < '%s'"%fname,"rb") as stream:
            unpickler = cPickle.Unpickler(stream)
            unpickler.find_global = unpickle_find_global
            return unpickler.load()
    else:
        with open(fname,"rb") as stream:
            unpickler = cPickle.Unpickler(stream)
            unpickler.find_global = unpickle_find_global
            return unpickler.load()
```

UPDATE: Hi, please note that I have used Python's native gzip, and it is working fine. Thank you for pointing that out. Here is the correct syntax that is working on Windows: {with gzip.GzipFile(fname,"rb") as stream:}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `gunzip` (in the `load_object` function) is incorrect. Unless passed the `-c` argument, `gunzip` writes the decompressed data to a new file, *not* to its stdout (which is what you seem to be attempting to do).

As a result, it doesn't write anything to its stdout, and your `stream` variable contains no data, hence the `EOFError`.

A quick fix is to change your `gunzip` command line to give it the `-c` argument.

More info here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip

That said, why are you even shelling out to `gunzip` to decompress your data? Python's built-in `gzip` module should handle that without problems.